# this is the error i m getting Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, mean-stack

**Error**:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:535:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\Abubakar\Desktop\Desktop Docs\Full Stack Web Devop Data\FPLatest\FinalFullstack\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\Abubakar\Desktop\Desktop Docs\Full Stack Web Devop Data\FPLatest\FinalFullstack\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\Abubakar\Desktop\Desktop Docs\Full Stack Web Devop Data\FPLatest\FinalFullstack\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
    at C:\Users\Abubakar\Desktop\Desktop Docs\Full Stack Web Devop Data\FPLatest\FinalFullstack\API\Routes\Signuproutes.js:109:13
    at C:\Users\Abubakar\Desktop\Desktop Docs\Full Stack Web Devop Data\FPLatest\FinalFullstack\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4876:16
    at C:\Users\Abubakar\Desktop\Desktop Docs\Full Stack Web Devop Data\FPLatest\FinalFullstack\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:16:11
    at C:\Users\Abubakar\Desktop\Desktop Docs\Full Stack Web Devop Data\FPLatest\FinalFullstack\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4899:21
    at C:\Users\Abubakar\Desktop\Desktop Docs\Full Stack Web Devop Data\FPLatest\FinalFullstack\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:493:16
    at C:\Users\Abubakar\Desktop\Desktop Docs\Full Stack Web Devop Data\FPLatest\FinalFullstack\node_modules\kareem\index.js:246:48
    at next (C:\Users\Abubakar\Desktop\Desktop Docs\Full Stack Web Devop Data\FPLatest\FinalFullstack\node_modules\kareem\index.js:167:27)
    at next (C:\Users\Abubakar\Desktop\Desktop Docs\Full Stack Web Devop Data\FPLatest\FinalFullstack\node_modules\kareem\index.js:169:9)
    at Kareem.execPost (C:\Users\Abubakar\Desktop\Desktop Docs\Full Stack Web Devop Data\FPLatest\FinalFullstack\node_modules\kareem\index.js:217:3)
    at _handleWrapError (C:\Users\Abubakar\Desktop\Desktop Docs\Full Stack Web Devop Data\FPLatest\FinalFullstack\node_modules\kareem\index.js:245:21)
    at _cb (C:\Users\Abubakar\Desktop\Desktop Docs\Full Stack Web Devop Data\FPLatest\FinalFullstack\node_modules\kareem\index.js:304:16)
    at C:\Users\Abubakar\Desktop\Desktop Docs\Full Stack Web Devop Data\FPLatest\FinalFullstack\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:344:9
Emitted 'error' event on Function instance at:
    at C:\Users\Abubakar\Desktop\Desktop Docs\Full Stack Web Devop Data\FPLatest\FinalFullstack\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4878:13
    at C:\Users\Abubakar\Desktop\Desktop Docs\Full Stack Web Devop Data\FPLatest\FinalFullstack\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:16:11
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at C:\Users\Abubakar\Desktop\Desktop Docs\Full Stack Web Devop Data\FPLatest\FinalFullstack\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:344:9
    at C:\Users\Abubakar\Desktop\Desktop Docs\Full Stack Web Devop Data\FPLatest\FinalFullstack\node_modules\kareem\index.js:135:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11) {
  code: 'ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT'
```

**Code**:

```js
  const express=require('express');

  const router=express.Router();

  require("dotenv").config()

  const user = require('..//Models/User.js')

  const Posts=require('../Models/Posts')

  const comments=require('../Models/comments')

  const bcrypt=require('bcrypt')

  const jwt=require("jsonwebtoken")

  const mongoose=require('mongoose')
  mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/useres23213s",{useCreateIndex: true,useNewUrlParser: true,useUnifiedTopology: true})




  //Getting All Users
  router.get('/Users',async(req,res,next)=>{

      await user.find(function(err,user){

        if(err)
        throw err

          res.json(user)

            })
    res.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
  });


  //Getting All Blogs
  router.get('/GetBlogs',(req,res,next)=>{

    Posts.find(function(err,Posts){

    if(!err){



      res.json(Posts)

    }})

  });





  //Sign Up User
  router.post('/Users',(req,res)=>{


    let newuser=new user( {


      name:req.body.name,
      email:req.body.email,
      password:req.body.password,


  });


    if(!req.body.name || !req.body.email || !req.body.password){


      res.json("Please fill the Credentials")
      res.end()
      return

    }

    user.findOne({name:req.body.name},(err,User)=>{

      if(User)
      {

          res.json("User Name Already Registered")
          res.end()
          return
      }

    })


  user.findOne({email:req.body.email},(err,User)=>{
    if(User)
    {
      res.json("Email Already Registered")
      res.end()
      return
    }

  })

  newuser.save((err,user)=>
  {
      if (err)

      {
        res.json({msg:' Failed adding User in Database'});
        res.end()
        throw err
        return
      }
      else
      {
          res.json({msg:' User added in Database'});;
          res.end()
      }
  })

  });






  process.env.SecretKey="SecretKey"
  //User Login
  router.post('/Login',(req,res)=>{

    if(!req.body.password || !req.body.name){
      return res.json({success:false,msg:"Please Fill the Credentials"})
    }

    user.findOne({name:req.body.name},(err,User)=>{

      if(err || !User){

        return res.json({success:false,msg:"Username not Registered"})

            }
    else
    {
        if(req.body.password!=User.password)
        {
                  return res.json({success:false,msg:"Password Invalid"})
        }

        const payload={

          id:User._id,
          email:User.email,
          Username:User.Username,

        }
        date=Date.now()
        token=jwt.sign({payload},process.env.SecretKey,(err,token)=>{

            res.json({success:true,msg:"User Logged in",token,Userid:{Userid:User.email},UserloggedIn:{UserloggedIn:date}})

          })
    }
  })
  })







  router.post('/postcomment',(req,res)=>{
    let newcomment=new comments({

      commentBody:req.body.commentBody,
      commentCreatedBy:req.body.commentCreatedBy,
      Posttitle:req.body.Posttitle
    })



    if(!req.body.commentBody){

      res.json({success:false,msg:"Enter Comment Body"})
      return

    }




    //Posting a comment
    newcomment.save((err,comment)=>{

      if(err)
      {
        res.json({success:false,msg:"Error in Posting Comment"})
        throw err
        return

      }
      else
      {
        res.json({success:true,msg:"Comment Posted..",comment})
      }

    })
  })



  //Creating a Post/Blog/Question
  router.post('/CreatePost',(req,res)=>{
    let newpost=new Posts({
        title:req.body.title,
        Body:req.body.Body,
        CreatedBy:req.body.CreatedBy,
        Createdat:req.body.Createdat,
    })

    if(!req.body.title)
    {
      res.json({
        success:false,
        msg:"Post Must have A title"
      })
      return
    }



    if(!req.body.Body){
      res.json({
        success:false,
        msg:"Post Must have A title"
      })
      return
    }

    newpost.save((err,post)=>{

      if(!err)
        {
          res.json(
            {success:true,
            msg:"Post Saved"}
            )

      }
      else
      throw err
      return
    })

    res.json({
      success:true,
      msg:"Posted.."
    })})
  module.exports=router;
```

Comment: `res.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');` should be written before `res.json(user)`, you can't set the header after the data is sent, and that's what the message says clearly, error messages exist for helping you debug your code, don't panic and read them carefully to see what's wrong in future coding.

Answer (score 1):

looks like this part is what is causing the error

```
router.get('/Users',async(req,res,next)=>{

      await user.find(function(err,user){

        if(err)
        throw err

          res.json(user)

            })
    res.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
  });
```

i see a couple of issues with this part:-

1. you don't need async/await since you are providing callbacks. if you want to use async/await i suggest a refactor.
2. `if(err)` and `throw err` needs to be on the same line if you want to avoid running the rest of the code and you need a return statement.
3. the main issue which is `res.json(user)` is executing before `res.setHeader()` that's why you are getting the error. also you don't need to set the header to `application/json` if you are using `res.json()`

so something along those lines should work

```
router.get('/Users', ( req, res )=>{

      // i am assuming that's how the model works to get all users. change if needed
      user.find({}, function(err, users){

        if(err) throw new Error(err)

        res.json(users)

    })
  });
```

Hope this helps!